# Combine two cypher queries

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, cypher-3.1

Currently this is the data stored in the database

```
Org Name   Org ID
A            1
B            2
C            5
D            9
```

I'm trying to combine these 2 queries:

```
MATCH (n:Org)
WHERE n.id in [1,2]
RETURN n.name as group1_name, n.id as group1_id

MATCH (n:Org)
WHERE n.id in [5,9]
RETURN n.name as group2_name, n.id as group2_id
```

I need the result to be shown like this:

```
group1_id   group1_name   group2_id   group1_name
1                A           5          C
2                B           9          D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the two id lists are always the *same size* (in your example, 2), here is one approach (assuming you also want the id values sorted in ascending order):

```
MATCH (n:Org)
WHERE n.id in [1, 2]
WITH n ORDER BY n.id
WITH COLLECT(n) AS ns
MATCH (m:Org)
WHERE m.id in [5, 9]
WITH ns, m ORDER BY m.id
WITH ns, COLLECT(m) AS ms
UNWIND [i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(ns)-1) | {a: ns[i], b: ms[i]}] AS row
RETURN
  row.a.id as group1_id, row.a.name as group1_name,
  row.b.id as group2_id, row.b.name as group2_name
```

And here is a simpler approach:

```
WITH [1, 2] AS xs, [5, 9] AS ys
UNWIND RANGE(0, SIZE(xs)-1) AS i
MATCH (n:Org), (m:Org)
WHERE n.id = xs[i] AND m.id = ys[i]
RETURN n.id as group1_id, n.name as group1_name, m.id as group2_id, m.name as group2_name
```

And finally, if the `xs` and `ys` lists are passed to the query as [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/):

```
UNWIND RANGE(0, SIZE($xs)-1) AS i
MATCH (n:Org), (m:Org)
WHERE n.id = $xs[i].id AND m.id = $ys[i].y
RETURN n.id as group1_id, n.name as group1_name, m.id as group2_id, m.name as group2_name
```